# I want to render line chart using grouping on particular field

Tags: extjs, charts, grouping, extjs4.1

Currently I am rendering single line chart using json data which is as follow :

```
{"eventType":"A","startOpen":"0","asOfDate":"21-OCT-13","intervalNo":0},
{"eventType":"A","startOpen":"47","asOfDate":"21-OCT-13","intervalNo":1},
{"eventType":"A","startOpen":"60","asOfDate":"21-OCT-13","intervalNo":2},
{"eventType":"B","startOpen":"79","asOfDate":"21-OCT-13","intervalNo":4},
{"eventType":"B","startOpen":"90","asOfDate":"21-OCT-13","intervalNo":6}
```

I am plotting graph `startOpen` against `intervalNo`. Now I want to plot the graph using grouping on `eventType` field. Means for above data two line should be drawn in single chart, one for eventType `A` and another for eventType `B`.

Appreciate your any kind of help. Thank you :)

My current code for chart :

```
Ext.define("TestBug.view.TrendsChart", {
extend: "Ext.chart.Chart",
alias: "widget.trendschart",
store: "Trends",
style: 'background:#fff',
animate: true,
shadow: true,
groupField:'eventType',

legend: {position: 'right'},
axes: [
    {
        type: "numeric",
        position: "left",
        fields: "intervalNo",
        title:"Interval No",
        grid: {
            odd: {
                opacity: 1,
                fill: '#ddd',
                stroke: '#bbb',
                'stroke-width': 0.5
            }
        }
   },
    {
        type: "numeric",
        position: "bottom",
        fields: "startOpen",
        title: 'Start Open'
    }
],
series: [
    {
        type: "line",
        axis: "left",
        xField: "startOpen",
        yField: "intervalNo",
        gField:'eventType',
        markerConfig: {
            type: 'circle',
            size: 4,
            radius: 4,
            'stroke-width': 0
        }
    }
]
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code you already have for the chart and store?

Comment: @forgivenson I updated my question. Please have a look. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to plot multiple lines width different x values, you have to use multiple line series. Value points with value of `undefined` will be skipped, that is they won't be drawn in the chart.

Here's how to adapt your example data to do that ([fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2jg)):

```
Ext.define("TestBug.view.TrendsChart", {
    extend: "Ext.chart.Chart",
    alias: "widget.trendschart",

    store: {
        fields: [
            'eventType', 
            {name: 'startOpen', type: 'int'}, 
            'asOfDate', 
            'intervalA',
            'intervalB'
        ]
        ,data: [
            {"eventType":"A","startOpen":"0","intervalA":0,"intervalB":undefined},
            {"eventType":"A","startOpen":"47","intervalA":1,"intervalB":undefined},
            {"eventType":"A","startOpen":"35","intervalA":undefined,"intervalB":2},
            {"eventType":"B","startOpen":"79","intervalA":undefined,"intervalB":4},
            {"eventType":"B","startOpen":"90","intervalA":undefined,"intervalB":6}
        ]
    },

    style: 'background:#fff',
    animate: true,
    shadow: true,
    groupField: 'eventType',

    legend: {
        position: 'right'
    },

    axes: [{
        type: "numeric",
        position: "left",
        fields: ["intervalA", "intervalB"],
        title: "Interval No",
        grid: {
            odd: {
                opacity: 1,
                fill: '#ddd',
                stroke: '#bbb',
                'stroke-width': 0.5
            }
        }
    },{
        type: "numeric",
        position: "bottom",
        fields: "startOpen",
        title: 'Start Open'
    }],

    series: [{
        type: "line",
        axis: "left",
        xField: "startOpen",
        yField: "intervalA",
        title: "A"
    },{
        type: "line",
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'startOpen',
        yField: 'intervalB',
        title: "B"
    }]
});

Ext.widget('trendschart', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,width: 600
    ,height: 300
});
```

Comment: I know this way to draw multi line chart. But I want to do it using my above json response. Anyways thanks for your reply :)

Comment: If your json format is a hard constraint, maybe you should say it in the question... If you know this, then you've got all you need for an automatic solution. See [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2l9) for example.

Comment: That's what I want. :D

Comment: Can you help me with another example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171049/dynamically-generate-axis-and-series-in-extjs-4